# Sympy returns zero for fractions with real numbers

Tags: python, sympy, fractions

I'm new to Sympy, and have realized it is quite nice for calculating and simplifying algebraic expressions.

However, when when I write fractions of real numbers it returns zero (no problem with fractions of symbols like 'x'). What am I doing wrong?

```
from sympy import *

1./2
Out[2]: 0.5

1/2
Out[3]: 0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's because python (2.7) needs a float in denominator or numerator to return a float.

in python 3.x any division returns a float

You can also 'fix' in python 2.7 that by using :

```
from __future__ import division
```

In fact python follow the integer division rules and return an integer and not a float number

Answer (score 0):

`1/2` isn't using SymPy at all. This is just evaluated by Python. Take a read of http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#two-final-notes-and (I actually recommend reading through the [whole SymPy tutorial](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/)).

Basically, if you are using SymPy, you probably want a rational number, which you can get with `Rational(1, 2)`. An easier way to type this is `S(1)/2`. The `S` function converts `1` into SymPy's `Integer(1)`, which then becomes a `Rational` when divided by.

Comment: I know. Problem occured if I wanted to solve equations like: x - 1/2 + a = 0, and you get that the solution is x=-a instead of x = 1/2 - a